# GeoServer REST API - curl example for creating ImageMosaic

Tags: geoserver, image-mosaic, rest

Does anyone have a curl example for using the GeoServer REST API to create an ImageMosaic?

The rasters (granules?)that I want to use local on the GeoServer file system. It work through the UI interface, but I can't get it to work with the REST API. I have tried many combinations of commands over many days and seek an example that works. Here is my latest attempt:

```
curl -X POST -u user:passwd -H "Content-Type: application/xml" -d "<coverageStore><name>test-mosaic</name><type>ImageMosaic</type><enabled>true</enabled><url>file:mosaics/testing/testmosaic</url></coverageStore>" "http://somehost.org/geoserver/rest/workspaces/test/coveragestores/test-mosaic/coverages.xml"
```

When I run this I get the following response:

> Cannot cast org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl to org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageInfo

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211717/geoserver-imagemosaic-creation-through-rest-api-with-postgis-granule-indexing solve your issue

Comment: or https://docs.geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/multidim/rest/index.html

Comment: or in python https://github.com/megamott/geoserver-imagemosaic-rest

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example how I do it. For convenience, I'm putting the commands in a bash script (in case you got multiple ImageMosaic layers to add).
Adapt the configurations to fit your data (mind that the `##create layer` part is quite extensive. You could probably take the `<dimensions></dimensions>` part out. Otherwise adapt accordingly). The folder with your rasters/granules can be anywhere, but GeoServer (or better the java servlet container e.g. Tomcat) needs read/write access though). The script should be self-explaining.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

##script takes 3 arguments
folderpath="$1" #path where all granules are
workspace="$2" #workspace name
layername="$3" #layer name


##geoserver credentials
user="xxx"
password="xxx"
geoserverurl="https://yourdomain.com/geoserver"
GridSetName="EPSG:3857" #Gridset, used for caching
style1='style1' #style of the layer
maxage=86400 #client-side caching, set to 0 if not wanted


##create workspace
curl -v -u $user:$password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<workspace><name>"$workspace"</name></workspace>" $geoserverurl"/rest/workspaces"


##add external imagemosaic
curl -v -u $user:$password -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain" -d "file://"$folderpath"/" $geoserverurl"/rest/workspaces/"$workspace"/coveragestores/"$workspace$layername"/external.imagemosaic"


##create layer
curl -v -u $user:$password -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<coverage><name>"$layername"</name><id>"$layername"</id><title>"$layername"</title><nativeCRS>EPSG:3857</nativeCRS><srs>EPSG:3857</srs><projectionPolicy>REPROJECT_TO_DECLARED</projectionPolicy><metadata><entry key=\"cacheAgeMax\">"$maxage"</entry><entry key=\"cachingEnabled\">true</entry></metadata><parameters><entry><string>BackgroundValues</string><string>255</string></entry><entry><string>OVERVIEW_POLICY</string><string>QUALITY</string></entry><entry><string>MergeBehavior</string><string>FLAT</string></entry><entry><string>AllowMultithreading</string><string>false</string></entry><entry><string>MaxAllowedTiles</string><string>-1</string></entry><entry><string>ExcessGranuleRemoval</string><string>NONE</string></entry><entry><string>OutputTransparentColor</string><string></string></entry><entry><string>USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD</string><string>true</string></entry><entry><string>Bands</string><string></string></entry><entry><string>RescalePixels</string><string>true</string></entry><entry><string>Filter</string><string></string></entry><entry><string>InputTransparentColor</string><string></string></entry><entry><string>SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE</string><string>512,512</string></entry><entry><string>Accurate resolution computation</string><string>false</string></entry><entry><string>SORTING</string><string></string></entry><entry><string>FootprintBehavior</string><string>Cut</string></entry></parameters><dimensions><coverageDimension><name>GRAY_INDEX</name><description>GridSampleDimension[-Infinity,Infinity]</description><range><min>-inf</min><max>inf</max></range><nullValues><double>255.0</double></nullValues><dimensionType><name>UNSIGNED_8BITS</name></dimensionType></coverageDimension></dimensions></coverage>" $geoserverurl"/rest/workspaces/"$workspace"/coveragestores/"$workspace$layername"/coverages/"$layername


##apply style
curl -v -u $user:$password -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<layer><defaultStyle><name>"$style1"</name><workspace>"$workspace"</workspace></defaultStyle></layer>" $geoserverurl"/rest/layers/"$workspace":"$layername""


##configure cached layer
curl -v -u $user:$password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<GeoServerLayer><enabled>true</enabled><inMemoryCached>true</inMemoryCached><name>"$workspace":"$layername"</name><mimeFormats><string>image/png8</string></mimeFormats><gridSubsets><gridSubset><gridSetName>"$GridSetName"</gridSetName></gridSubset></gridSubsets><metaWidthHeight><int>4</int><int>4</int></metaWidthHeight><expireCache>0</expireCache><expireClients>"$maxage"</expireClients><parameterFilters><styleParameterFilter><key>STYLES</key><defaultStyle>"$stylename"</defaultStyle></styleParameterFilter></parameterFilters><gutter>5</gutter></GeoServerLayer>" $geoserverurl"/gwc/rest/layers/"$workspace":"$layername""


##pre-seed tiles (zoom levels 0-10)
curl -v -u $user:$password -XPOST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<seedRequest><name>"$workspace":"$layername"</name><gridSetId>"$GridSetName"</gridSetId><zoomStart>0</zoomStart><zoomStop>10</zoomStop><format>image/png8</format><type>seed</type><threadCount>1</threadCount></seedRequest>" $geoserverurl"/gwc/rest/seed/"$workspace":"$layername".xml"
```